# Extract letters and numbers from string

Tags: stata

I have the following strings:

```
KZ1,345,769.1
PKS948,123.9   
XG829,823.5 
324JKL,282.7
456MJB87,006.01
```

How can I separate the letters and numbers?

This is the outcome I expect:

```
  KZ   1345769.1  
 PKS    948123.9  
  XG    829823.5  
 JKL    324282.7  
 MJB    45687006
```

I have tried using the `split` command for this purpose but without success.

Comment: `split` doesn't purport to address this kind of splitting. It requires parsing or punctuation characters to be present, such as spaces or commas to define elements.

Answer (score 0):

@Pearly Spencer's answer is surely preferable, but the following kind of naive looping should occur to any programmer. Look at each character in turn and decide whether it is a letter; or a number or decimal point; or something else (implicitly) and build up answers that way. Note that although we loop over the length of the string, looping over observations too is tacit.

```
clear 
input str42 whatever 
"KZ1,345,769.1"
"PKS948,123.9"   
"XG829,823.5" 
"324JKL,282.7"
"456MJB87,006.01"
end 

compress 

local length = substr("`: type whatever'", 4, .) 

gen letters = "" 
gen numbers = "" 

quietly forval j = 1/`length' { 
    local arg substr(whatever,`j', 1) 
    replace letters = letters + `arg' if inrange(`arg', "A", "Z") 
    replace numbers = numbers + `arg' if `arg' == "." | inrange(`arg', "0", "9") 
}

list 


     +-----------------------------------------+
     |        whatever   letters       numbers |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. |   KZ1,345,769.1        KZ     1345769.1 |
  2. |    PKS948,123.9       PKS      948123.9 |
  3. |     XG829,823.5        XG      829823.5 |
  4. |    324JKL,282.7       JKL      324282.7 |
  5. | 456MJB87,006.01       MJB   45687006.01 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Note that this creates a number variable which is a string.

Comment: Correct, so if someone wants the numeric version, they need to follow up with `destring` or `real()` with attention to storage type needed.